# How to save information based on what the user has clicked on (category)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

[example img of a category selection by user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGXlT.jpg)

Hey, I'm trying to set up a selection where the user has to pick a category and a second category and I have no idea how to get the information he clicked on.
After the user has clicked on the category it will add the .active and the next button appears.

After clicking the next button a formular (based on the category he picked) will fadeIn and I need the category Information, because after submitting the formular I want the category to be saved, too.

So, how can I save the information he clicked on? I don't want to use a dropdown or radiobuttons but I'm open to anything else (js / jquery, php)  if it looks like the example on the image.

I tried it with buttons like:

```
    <form id="cat1" method="post">
         <input type="submit" id="1st_cat_1" class="cat1" name="cat1" value="1st cat"><br>
         <input type="submit" id="1st_cat_2" class="cat1" name="cat2" value="1st cat"><br>
         <input type="submit" id="1st_cat_3" class="cat1" name="cat3" value="1st cat">
    </form>
```

I also thought about looking for the class-combo (which one has the .active when clicking the next button)
like:

```
    $('.cat1').click(function(){
       $('.cat1').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
    })
```

so the clicked category has both:

```
    /*$('.cat1.active')*/
```

But I don't know how to read this out,
This isn't the complete code for what I'm trying to do, but I only need to know the data save part. Please help me :(

Comment: Save what information? Not clear what you are needing

Comment: the category he clicked on.

For example: apples, bananas, eggs
User selects apples by clicking on it, then he clicks the "next" -button(which makes the formular show up): how can I check if he has clicked on apples?

Comment: you have `this` in all event handlers so you have access to all attributes and properties of `this`

Comment: ok, unfortunatelly I'm not familiar with all the properties of [this], can you help me out?

Comment: `this` is the element ... I don't know what data you are looking for based on that element

Comment: my whole question isn't based on any code. You came up with [this] element. 
The posted code were only my thoughts (as I wrote)

apples, bananas, eggs  = data;

user clicks on one of them -> how to save his choice into a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the value

```
<form id="cat1" method="post">
     <input type="submit" id="1st_cat_1" class="cat1" name="cat1" value="apple"><br>
     <input type="submit" id="1st_cat_2" class="cat1" name="cat2" value="banana"><br>
     <input type="submit" id="1st_cat_3" class="cat1" name="cat3" value="orange">
</form>
```

you can get the value from this method

```
$('.cat1').click(function(){
   $('.cat1').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   var v = $(this).val();//the v is apple or banana or orange
})
```

or just like that

```
var v = $('.cat1.active').val();//the v is apple or banana or orange
```

Comment: You Sir are a genious. Exactly, what I was looking for! Thank you so much for reading into my problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can cache off their selection like this:

```js
var food = 'apple'

function getFood(element) {
  food = document.getElementById('foods').value;
  console.log(food);
}
```

```html
<select id="foods" onChange="getFood(this);">
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
</select>
```